# storing greek letters in mysql table?

Tags: php, database

I want to store greek letters in mysql table my table collaction is `utf8_general_ci` and i'm calling this function after database connection

```
mysqli_query($connection, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($connection,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

but all greek letters in database are like "??????? ???" Question mark how to resolve this ???

I search on internet and eveyone says set characterset that i also set even in my html page i also have this line

someone says change `utf8_general_ci` to `greek_general_ci` but still have same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create your table like this?

```
  CREATE TABLE t1
    (
    col1 CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
    )
```

Comment: Try this 
mysqli_set_charset($connnection,"utf8");